# How to install X264

Tags: linux, gtk, dependencies, x264

I'm trying to make a program. When I run ./configure, this is what I get:

```
checking for X264... configure: WARNING:
Test application not built (x264 codec missing).
Either you have not installed x264, or you
have not installed it with the Gtk+ interface.
If you compile it from source, add these options
to configure:
--enable-shared
--enable-gtk
```

I have installed various packages that are related to x264 and gtk, but I'm still getting this message. Which packages do I need to install?

Comment: Check `config.log`, sometimes it'll give you a better hint for why it's failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this howto](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095) to install ffmpeg and x264 on my machine...

Comment: Even after following those instructions the message still appears.

Comment: When you followed those instructions, did you add "--enable-gtk --enable-shared" in the options in step three when compiling x264 ?